# storing and loading input data in localStorage step by step

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to use localStorage to store some input data.
This is what I came up with and no it does not work.
Can someone explain to me how I can get this to work?
 I have searched for tutorials but I find it hard to understand how to store and retrieve the data from the localStorage.
This is my script:

```
  <body onLoad="get();">

   <article id="hldr">
      <input type="text" id="kID" class="regTXTBOX" placeholder="office ID">
      <input type="text" id="gID" class="regTXTBOX" placeholder="user ID">
      <button id="save" onClick="store();" style="margin-bottom:20px;">save data</button>
      <button id="login" onClick="store();">log-in</button>
    </article>
  <span id="1"></span>
  <span id="2"></span>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function store(){
    var kid = document.getElementById("kID");
    localStorage.setItem("kidStore", kid.value);
}
function get(){
    var one = document.getElementById('1').value
    one = localStorage.getItem("kidStore");
}
</script>
  </body>
```

I want it to fire when the page loads, although I probably don't even need the onLoad function for that.
I also don't really need the button to save the data but I just put it in for testing.
If someone can provide me a step-by-step explanation to get this to work I would be very happy.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Because in your code, you're not using the output of `getItem`.

Comment: sorry, forgot it :P I want the variable "one" to be filled with the entry "kidStore".

Comment: Any errors? Did you include html5.js?

Comment: I don't get any errors and I did not include html5.js, do I need it?

Comment: You're setting the variable to value and then to the localStorage return value. Try it like this: `document.getElementById('1').value = localStorage.getItem("kidStore");`

Comment: I changed the get function to use the line you provided but still no difference

Comment: Sorry, my bad, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `span` element does not have a `value` property. So changing it to `innerText` will make it work (along with the assigning problem which I mentioned in the comments).

The following will work:

```
document.getElementById('1').innerText = localStorage.getItem("kidStore");
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6r53/

Comment: Nice that works now! Do you by any chance also know how to save this data without having to press the button?

Comment: @dennismuys Depends on when you want to save the data. You can call `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` at virtually any time.

Comment: okay I put the store function on <body onUnload""> to save when the user closes the page, I want to save as soon as the input is received and this works well enough.